# How to position an element to be center aligned with ClientWidth inside a horizontal list created with css flex-box by onClick event?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I've a horozontal list created using css flex-box.

```
<div onClick={() => setActive("item-1")}} className="item"><h2>Item-1</h2></div>
.
.
.
<div onClick={() => setActive("item-6")}} className="item"><h2>Item-1</h2></div>
</div>
```

For css

```
.horizontally-scrolled-items {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin: 6px 0;
}
.item {
  min-width: max-content;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: darkgrey;
  transition: font-weight 1.2s;
  transition: font-size 1.2s;
  transition: color 1.2s;
}
```

So with onClick when a single Item is active, I want to scroll it to the middle of the clientWidth ( screen ) , When someone clicks on another Item , that Item will be active and will be scrolled from intial from its initial position to the middle of the screen.
How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an array of refs using useRef() hook and then when a particular ref is clicked, you can use 'getBoundingClientRect()' and window.scrollTo to scroll to a particular location.For more info on getBoundingClientRect() and window.scrollTo check the docs:
1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

Before I begin explaining the solution,however, I see you have many `<divs>` created for your horizontal list. Rather than doing this manually as it is time consuming and doesn't allow for dynamic adding of more items to the list, a better solution is to call on an array to return divs using the .map() function in javascript. Now for the solution:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const Component = () => {
 var listRef = useRef([]);

const scrollToRef = (rect) => window.scrollTo((rect.right-rect.left)/2, (rect.top-rect.bottom)/2)

// setActiveItem() handles both the name of current Item as well as scroll position
const setActiveItem = (i) =>{
 var itemName = "item-"+i.toString();
 setActive(itemName);
 var rect = listRef.current[i].getBoundingClientRect();
 scrollToRef(rect);
};

const getAllLists = arr.map((listItem, i)=>(
  <div ref={(el) => (listRef.current[i] = el)} onClick={() => setActiveItem(i)}}
className="item"><h2>Item - {i}</h2></div>         
));

return (<div className="list">
  {getAllLists}
</div>);
};
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-williams-d88vv
Could you please check this sandbox and tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Finally figured it out by using "scrollBy". "getBoundingClientRect" worked like a charm. Updated the code in sandbox.